# Job runs randomly in Hangfire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cron, job-scheduling, hangfire

I have wrote cron expression which should run the method on after every 5 minutes but it runs continuously after random interval. 
Here is my code

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    HomeController home = new HomeController();
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangFireCon");
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        //app.UseHangfire(config=> {

        //    config.UseServer(1)

        //});
        var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = 1 };
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("UAERR284SSSSSS" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss"),() => home.GenerateFile(), "0 */5 * ? * *");
        app.UseHangfireServer(options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) you may try

```
*/5 * * * *
```

for your CRON expression